# TS2339: Property 'width' does not exist on type 'HTMLDivElement'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

[image]

What should I do

```
 this.container = document.getElementById(obj.id) as HTMLDivElement;   
 this.containerWidth =this.container.width;
 this.containerHeight = this.container.height
```

Comment: Try using this.container.style.width and this.container.style.height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `offsetWidth`:
[offsetWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth) and [offsetHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight)

```
this.containerWidth =this.container.offsetWidth;
this.containerHeight = this.container.offsetHeight
```

You saw this error because [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) don't have property width.

Comment: thanks , That solves my problem but I don't understand why。

Comment: I linked a document about HTMLElement. You can read the doc for more details